# Python delete certain lines from file

Tags: python-3.5

I have a csv file that looks like following:

```
CCC, rev, pIndex, no.
23, 2.5, 0, 4
34, 4.3, 1, 3
27, 7.9, 2, 5
12, 5.7, 3, 7
```

where the third element in each line is called the `pIndex`. I have code that replicates each line once, while updating the `pIndex` accordingly. So the output looks like following:

```
CCC, rev, pIndex, no.
23, 2.5, 0, 4
23, 2.5, 1, 4
34, 4.3, 2, 3
34, 4.3, 3, 3
27, 7.9, 4, 5
27, 7.9, 5, 5
12, 5.7, 6, 7
12, 5.7, 7, 7
```

Below is the code that does that:

```
with fileinput.input(inplace=True) as f:
    n = 0
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        numbers = line.split(sep = ',')
        for i in range(2):
            numbers[3] = n
            n += 1
            s = ''
            for j in numbers:
                s += str(j) + ','
            s = s.rstrip(',')
            print(s)
```

Now I want to delete one duplication each of the first and last line, so basically delete the first line (after header, with `pIndex` 0) and the last line in the file. I am using `fileinput` and trying to write the result back in the same file. I tried

```
result = []
result.append(s)
```

which makes each line a separate array. I would then make another array
`result_all` that will contain all the lines(as arrays) and then do `result_all[1:-1]` to get rid of the first and last line. But this does not seem to work well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use can iterate in lines and skip line 1 and last line, you need to know the number lines though.

```
with open('thatfile', 'r') as file:
   num_of_lines = file.read().count('\n')
   file.seek(0)
   i = 0
   with open('newfile', 'w') as newfile:
      for line in file:
         if i != 1 and i != num_of_lines:
            newfile.write(line)
         i = i + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to make it general for a lot of files, so I would like to pass it in command line like `python script.py filename.csv`